# Bluetooth A2DP SINK in Windows 8.1

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8.1, a2dp

I know Microsoft doesn't allow the streaming of music from phones to Windows 8 PC's or the use of the PC as hands free, but has anyone found a way around this yet?

Are there any modified drivers or ways to modify the current drivers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also looking for a solution here. Anyone found anyway to make windows 8/10 accept bluetooth audio input?

Answer (score 0):

www.bluesoleil.com offer a custom bluetooth driver that will make your pc show up as a Bluetooth headset to other devices. It will also allow you to choose which audio device the audio is repeated repeat to.

Product is not free but is the only solution is managed to find after half an afternoon looking. Works great as well.